# how to store the response of a system call from R studio to Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, system

Not sure how to best ask this. I want to store the response of a system command in R studio Mac.

For example, this command:

```
system("pwd")
```

Returns this:

```
/Volumes/chart/chart
```

I would like to store the return in a variable like this:

```
result <- system("pwd")
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `intern` parameter.

```
result <- system('pwd', intern = T)
result
#> [1] "/Volumes/chart/chart"
```